# Python: Importing multiple methods from external module

Tags: python

With very common Python modules, I find that importing using the `from .. import` statement greatly increases the readability of my code, since I can reference methods by name without the dot notation. However, in some modules, the methods I require are nested differently, e.g in `os`:

```
from os.path import join
from os import listdir, getcwd
```

Why doesn't `from os import path.join, listdir, getcwd` work? What would be a "pythonic" way to import all the methods I need in a more succinct manner?

Answer (score 0):

The opinion on whether `from <module> import <identifier>` is *Pythonic* itself is quite split - it hides away the origin of a method so it's not easy to figure out whence a certain variable/function comes from just by perusing the code. On the other hand, it reduces verbosity which some people consider *Pythonic* even tho it's not specifically mandated. Either way, *Pythonic* is as elusive term as you're going to get and more often than not it means "*the way I think Python code should look like*" backed up by several PEPs and obscure mail list posts while conveniently omitting the ones that go against one's notion of *Pythonic*.

`from os import path.join` doesn't work because `os` defines the `os.path` **module** (by directly writing to `sys.modules` of all things), it's not an identifier in the `os` module itself. `path`, however, is an identifier in the `os` module pointing to the `os.path` module so you can do `from os import path` or `from os.path import join`.

Finally, *succinct* and *Pythonic* are not synonyms, in fact [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) for example prescribes using multiple lines for multiple imports even tho you can *succinctly* write `import <module1>, <module2>, <module3> ...`. It says that it's OK to import multiple identifiers like that, tho, but keep in mind that `os` and `os.path` are two different modules so based on PEP 8 they shouldn't be on the same line and therefore should be written as:

```
from os import <identifier_1>, <identifier_2>
from os.path import <identifier_3>, <identifier_4>
```

Now, I would go as far as claiming that this is *Pythonic* but it makes the most sense based on PEP 8, at least to me.